# Can't Update Notifications text after Forerground service init; Context issue

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, nanohttpd, foreground-service

I have a simple NanoHTTPD server running as a foreground service.

I am facing issues in updating the notifications with new content when a new request to a server comes in.

The foreground service starts up and the notification shows. No issue there. But can't update them later.

File structure
- Mainactivity
- NanoServer *(server implementaion)*
- NanoService *(foreground service class)*
- NotificationProvider *(separate class to handle notifications)*

NanoServer.java

```
    public Context context = getContext();
    public NotificationProvider notificationProvider;

    public NanoServer(int port) {
        super(8089);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(String uri, Method method,
                          Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parameters,
                          Map<String, String> files) {
        String answer = "";
        String msg;

        // doesnt work with the context. something wrong here I guess????
        notificationProvider = new NotificationProvider();
        notificationProvider.setNotification(context, "Title", uri, 0);

        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(uri);
            Log.w(TAG, uri + " found");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newChunkedResponse(Status.OK, "audio/mpeg", fis);

    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
```

NanoService.java

```
    String TAG = "NANOSERVICE";
    public Context context = this;
    public Handler handler = null;
    public static Runnable runnable = null;
    PowerManager powerManager;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    private NanoServer nanoServer;
    public NotificationProvider notificationProvider;

    public NanoService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Start the httpd.
        try {
            nanoServer = new NanoServer(8089);
            nanoServer.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Service with server started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service failed to start.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Keep the CPU awake (but not the screen).
        powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        wakeLock.acquire();

        // Keep the WIFI turned on.
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, TAG);
        wifiLock.acquire();

        notificationProvider = new NotificationProvider();
        notificationProvider.setNotification(this, "Title", "Message", 0);

        // had to extend notificationprovider with notification
        startForeground(1, notificationProvider);
        Log.d(TAG, "Foreground service running");

        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
        wakeLock.release();
        wifiLock.release();
        nanoServer.stop();
    }
```

NotificationProvider.java

```
public class NotificationProvider extends Notification {
    String TAG = "NOTIFICATIONPROVIDER";
    public NotificationProvider() {
    }

    public void setNotification(Context context, String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage, int notificationRequestCode){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                        .setContentText(notificationMessage)
                        .setTicker("My service")
                        .setColor(101)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Got new Notification");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution will be using the same builder method for updating the notification.

Use this updated `NotificationProvider`.

Change `new NotificationProvider()` to `NotificationProvider.getInstance()` in `NanoService` (or anywhere else).

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.iroid.videoeditor.R;
import com.iroid.videoeditor.main.MainActivity;

public class NotificationProvider extends Notification {

    private static NotificationProvider sInstance;

    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private String TAG = "NOTIFICATIONPROVIDER";

    public static NotificationProvider getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new NotificationProvider();

        return sInstance;
    }

    // Prevent creating new instances from outside
    private NotificationProvider() {
    }

    public void setNotification(Context context, String notificationTitle, String
            notificationMessage, int notificationRequestCode) {

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context
                .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (mBuilder == null) {
            // Notification doesn't exists. Need to create one.
            mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                            .setContentText(notificationMessage)
                            .setTicker("My service")
                            .setColor(101)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setOngoing(true)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    notificationRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
            Log.d(TAG, "Got new Notification");
        } else {
            // Notification exists. Simply update
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I stil need to provide the `context` in `setNotification`. That created problems in the non-activity class NanoServer. So will this still work? Is the way I have defined the context in NanoServer correct?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about it. But I think it will be okay and I use application context (`getApplicationContext()`) normally in similar situations.

Comment: Alright I am having trouble with that. In the nonactivety class Nanoserver, can you show what you did?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to be with your Notification ID, which must be unique within your application if you later want to update it.

```
manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Change it to a non-zero constant

```
private static final int NOTE_ID = 2794; //chosen arbitrarily

manager.notify(NOTE_ID, builder.build());
```

However you should also not hold (leak) a context, instead get the app context (or service context) when you use it.

**To be able to get an Application Context at any time**, implement an application class (and register it in the manifest)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static Context appContext() {
        return this;
    }

}

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="...">

    <!-- The name here should match whatever you called your application class -->
    <application android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is proper, safe, wont leak memory, or efficient. but I did manage to solve it by passing the context to the Nanoserver.java from the service class, where the server is initialized. That way I have access to context within.

Comment: Ok, I am sure - It is creating a leak (and also potential crashes). A better option is to use the application class singleton so you can do MyApp.getAppContext(). Context is a tricky object

Comment: Can you provide a sample? `getAppContext()` inside non-activity class wont work. I have checked various SO how to do this. No luck. It was then I figured why not pass the service context itself as a parameter while starting the server?

Comment: Well there is no app crashes I have noticed. But only thing which doesn't work is the foreground service itself. I do get 30-40 min activity but after that the phone kills it. For some reason it is not honoring the wakelock, I can see this - `PowerManager: WakeLock finalized while still held`

Comment: Take a look at the extra code I've added, that's how you make an application singleton

Comment: Do I have to modify the default application, `MainActivity` which you get when you create the app in the studio for the first time? Or I can just drop those lines in the manifest without anything inside?

Comment: Hey, it's a completely separate class you can create next to MainActivity (in my example, called MyApplication)